# Using shinyjs to hide/show ui elements

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I've been working on a shiny app and it's working OK (see https://ostaski.shinyapps.io/NextWordPredictR/).

Here's the relevant code:

```
    # ui.R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),  # Set up shinyjs
  titlePanel("Next Word PredictR"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel("Top Next Words",
                 br(" "),
                 shinyjs::hidden # this hides topWords, but toggleState in server.R doesn't toggle!?!
                 (
                     tableOutput('topWords')
                 )
    ),

    mainPanel("Enter word(s) in the box below or click a button", # this works
    br(" "),
      tags$head(
        tags$style(HTML("
                          #button1, #button2, #button3, #button4
                          {
                            color: #FFFFFF;
                            font-weight: bold;
                            background-color: #00AEAE;
                            border-color: #FFFFFF;
                          }
                          #text
                          {
                            width: 82%;
                          }
                        "))
        ),
      tags$div(
          tags$textarea(id = 'text', label = 'Enter word(s) in the box below or click a button', rows = 2, class='form-control', "")), # label is not working
          br(" "),
          htmlOutput("firstWord", inline = T),
          htmlOutput("secondWord", inline = T),
          htmlOutput("thirdWord", inline = T),
          htmlOutput("fourthWord", inline = T),
          br(" "),
          p('Below are five sentences drawn from the English news corpus you can copy/paste into the box above. HINT: do not copy/paste the ellipses (...) or the next words (in bold).'),
          HTML('Another strong month of hiring makes it less likely that the Federal Reserve will take additional steps to boost the economy at its meeting next ... <strong>week.</strong>'),
          HTML('<br /><br />When Junior walked into the memorial service Sunday, "it was a surprise to everyone," Doug Smith, Oceanside&#8217;s postmaster, told ... <strong>me.</strong>'),
          HTML('<br /><br />&quot;The Voice,&quot; NBC&#8217;s upstart singing competition, is back for its second season Sunday, and the network is kicking it off in prime-time style -- positioning it right after the Super ... <strong>Bowl.</strong>'),
          HTML('<br /><br />The main health issue that caused Meyer to resign at UF was a sick program he left on life ... <strong>support.</strong>'),
          HTML('<br /><br />Scarlett Johansson filmed scenes at an old warehouse on Ashland Road near Longfellow Avenue, off Cedar Road near the Norfolk Southern railroad ... <strong>tracks.</strong>'),
          HTML('<br /><br /><strong>DISCLAIMER:</strong>  Yes, of course I cherry-picked these sentences. The grand majority of sentences I tested failed miserably. &#9786;')
        )
      )
      )
    )
    # server.R
    library(shiny)
    library(shinyjs)
    library(tm)
    library(qdap)
    library(dplyr)

    allGrams <- readRDS("allGrams.rds")

    predict <- function (inputString, allGrams) 
    {
    ...
    }

    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    observe({
    ...
            shinyjs::toggleState("topWords", !is.null(input$text) && input$text != "") # these don't work either
#            shinyjs::toggleState("topWords", is.null(input$text) || input$text == "")
    ...

       })
    })
```

I am trying to hide the topwords and buttons when the page loads, then show them when words are entered into the textarea. `shinyjs::hidden()` in **ui.R** does hide the topwords in my test, but `shinyjs::toggleState()` in **server.R** doesn't show topwords when I enter some text in the textarea.

I've been at this for a few days, so maybe this is something obvious ... maybe it's just the condition added to `shinyjs::toggleState()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I managed to figure it out. Rather than using shinyjs::toggleState() in **server.R**, I changed it to just shinyjs::toggle() and now I get the desired effect.

It seems to alter the predictions, though, adding two words instead of just one.

I'll keep banging away at it.

Comment: Seems the shiny community is a bit miserly in upvoting. I usually find good stuff that is still lying with zero votes. Do I get happy too early?

Comment: toggle and toggleState are very different functions. Please look at their documentation - toggle is for showing/hiding, and toggleState is to enable/disable